# Reducing the whitespace between two divs in CSHTML

Tags: html, razor, model-view-controller

**Problem Statement:**
I'm trying to reduce the white-space between two divs.Actually when i inspected the elements,i didn't notice any white-space between them.So is there anyway i can overflow on each other or Is there anything which i'm doing wrong??

**HTML Code:**

```
 <div style="text-align:center;position:absolute;left:20px;top:5px;">
        <div style="font-size:150px;color:black;">
            @Html.Label("lblTarget", "1234"))
         </div>
         <div style="font-size:70px;color:black;">
             @Html.Label("lblLang", "Some Test Data")
         </div>
  </div>
```

1)Image showing the output for the above html code:
[image: Image1]

2)Desired Output which i'm trying to display:

[image: Image2]

*What css i need to apply inorder to get desired output shown in the second image??*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the looks of it you need to adjust the line-height of the text to achieve that effect

Comment: Thanks line height of the div solved my problem.I used `line-height: 100px;` in the main div

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the `font-size` increases the gap above and below the text - by default the full height of text is about 1.2 times the actual letter height, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values).

You need to change the `line-height` of the `div`s to about `0.9em` to reduce the gap.

```css
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}

div{
    line-height:0.9em;
}
```

```html
 <div style="text-align:center;position:absolute;left:20px;top:5px;">
        <div style="font-size:150px;color:black;">
            <label for="lblTarget">1234</label>
         </div>
         <div style="font-size:70px;color:black;">
             <label for="lblLang">Some Test Data</label>
         </div>
  </div>
```